# Android ListView added item twice

Tags: android, json, list, adapter

I'm parsing images and link from a website using JSON and add them to ListView:

```
    exploresAdapter = new ExploreListAdapter(context, new ArrayList<Explore>());
    listView_Explore.setAdapter(exploresAdapter);

    Document document = Jsoup.connect(Server.EXPLORE_LINK).timeout(10 * 1000).get();

    Elements divs = document.select("div[class=module-img] a[href]");

    for (Element div : divs) {
        try {
            href = div.attr("href");

            Elements a = document.select("a[href=" + href + "] img[src]");
                    src = a.attr("src");

            final Bitmap thumbnail = Global.bitmapFromUrl(src);

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Explore explore = new Explore();
                    explore.setUrl(href);
                    explore.setThumbnail(thumbnail);

                    exploresAdapter.add(explore);
                 }
            });
         } catch (Exception any) {
         //broken link or images, skip
         }
    }
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class ExploreListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public interface Callback {
    public void onPageRequested(int page);
}

private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<Explore> explores;

public ExploreListAdapter(Context ctx, List<Explore> explores) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.explores = explores;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.explores.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    Explore explore = this.explores.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_explore, parent, false);

        holder.imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail.setImageBitmap(explore.getThumbnail());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail;
}

public void add(Explore explore) {
    this.explores.add(explore);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    this.explores.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<Explore> getList() {
    return this.explores;
}
}
```

Explore object:

```
public class Explore {

private Bitmap thumbnail;
private String url;

public Explore() {

}

public void setThumbnail(Bitmap thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public Bitmap getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
}
```

At this point, the items are added twice. Weirdly when I check the items inside the list, they are all in perfect order with no duplicate. I've spent nearly 2 hours on this, any suggestion will be great.

Comment: Use log and check how many times `add` method is calling?

Comment: Your getItem() looks wrong off the bat.

Comment: And I believe you are getting this issue specially when you start scrolling your List up and down.?? Corrrect

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK the log says it was called as many as it should be, the size of the list is right, but the contents are just doubled

Comment: @MDMalik not really no, even the first content is already doubled. Scrolling has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: the last item on the listview is not doubled, if that information helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getItem()` method seems suspect - you are only returning the ID, not the actual item. It should be something like:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return explores.get(position);
}
```

**EDIT**

I vaguely recall having a similar issue at one point with a custom `ListView`/`Adapter` combination, but I can't exactly remember what the solution was. Have you tried adding the new elements to the `ArrayList` and then updating the `Adapter` instead of adding the new element directly to the `Adapter`? Something like the following:

```
ArrayList<Explore> arrayList = new ArrayList<Explore>();
```

Then when you want to add a new element...

```
Explore explore = new Explore();
explore.setUrl(href);
explore.setThumbnail(thumbnail);                
arrayList.add(explore);
exploresAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, adding a `Constructor` to your `Explore` class would be beneficial:

```
public Explore (Bitmap thumbnail, String url)
{
    super();
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.url = url;
}
```

Then you could add a new element to your `ListView` with two simple lines:

```
arrayList.add(new Explore(thumbnail, href));
exploresAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: my bad, never really paid attention on that one. But I'm afraid that didn't fix the problem

Comment: MY VERY BAD
the actual problem was Global.bitmapFromUrl() that fails to retrieve image from url, instead use the old one. So technically the List displays the correct amount of items, just duplicate picture. Sorry to cause you so much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
a)

```
public ExploreListAdapter(Context ctx, List<Explore> explores) {
inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

b)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_explore, null);
            imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail);

        } else {
            imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail);

        }
 imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail.setImageBitmap(explore.getThumbnail());



    return vi;
}
```

c) I have declare `imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail` below

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageView imageView_ExploreAdapter_Thumbnail;
```